# Aws s3 reduced redundancy costs the same as standard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I typed in the same parameters on s3 calculator for rss and standard and the result seems the same. I put in 10M put requests and 10M get requests for both and they came out to $5.38 under us-east zone.

Am i missing something here?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The requests do cost the same for both types of storage it costs exactly the same.

The pricing differences come down to cost per GB. For example storing 100GB in standard S3 storage will cost you $3. Storing the same amount of data in reduced redundancy will cost you $2,4.

Pricing for standard can be found here: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/.

While pricing for Reduced can be found here: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/reduced-redundancy/.

**Update**: As the comment below points out, now the the price for Standard storage is $0,023 per GB, so 100GB would cost $2,4 while the Reduced stayed at the same cost.

Now there's another option called  *Standard - Infrequent Access Storage*, which has the same benefits of S3 Standard and has a cost of 0.0125 per GB, so storing 100GB on tier would cost $1,25, but there are some caveats to watch for:

- Minimum object size of 128KB.
- Minimum storage duration of 30 days (if you delete the object before you'll be billed for 30 days).
- A per GB retrieval fee ($0.01 per GB) similar to the one present in AWS Glacier.

Comment: As of 2016 December 1, reduced redundancy is actually more expensive in storage too. Standard went down to $2.30 for 100 GB, while the reduced redundancy price stayed the same at $2.40. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-storage-update-s3-glacier-price-reductions/

Comment: The reason for RR being more expensive is described at https://mysteriouscode.io/blog/aws-s3-storage-classes-pricing-is-not-what-you-think/ - "S3’s goal is to eventually deprecate the RRS storage class, hence Standard currently being cheaper ($0.023 vs $0.024). We advise to switch any data under the RRS storage class to either Standard or one of the archive classes."

Answer (score -1):

Refer below document.

https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Anyways, pricing differs from Region to Region, No. of put/get requests and on data transfer.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I think you are missing the crucial point of my question being about "reduced redundancy" s3 plan vs the "standard" s3 plan.

Comment: suppose you are storing 100GB data with 10M put and get requests, Standard S3 costs - $56.83 and RRS S3 costs - $56.38....Amazon S3’s standard and reduced redundancy options both store data in multiple facilities and on multiple devices, but with RRS, data is replicated fewer times, so the cost is less. Amazon S3 standard storage is designed to provide 99.999999999% durability and to sustain the concurrent loss of data in two facilities, while RRS is designed to provide 99.99% durability and to sustain the loss of data in a single facility

Comment: Im fully aware of the technical difference regarding reliability and that wasn't the point of my question. Since you brought up some dollar figures here, altho i do believe they are true, the difference between the two seems so minuscule. To a point where why have the "redundancy" plan at all. Thats the reason why i asked my question.

Comment: well on a large scale this makes a lot of difference...for 10TB data with 10M get and put requests it is; Standard S3 costs - $412.83 and RRS S3 costs - $296.06. Hope this provides you the required info